# Is there a cleaner way to set this up?

Tags: ember.js, datepicker

I've wrapped a bootstrap-datepicker in an Ember view, but I'm not too happy with the results. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
App.DatepickerView = Ember.View.extend({

  classNames: ['dp'],

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var _this = this;

    this.$().datepicker({'format': 'M yyyy','minViewMode': 'months'})
      .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).datepicker().data('date').replace(" ", "-");

        _this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('month', App.Month.find(id));
      });

    this.$('.month.active').removeClass('active');

    if (this.get('controller.controllers.month.content')) {
      this.update();
    }

  },

  update: function() {
    var month = moment( this.get('controller.controllers.month.id') );
    this.$().datepicker('hide');
    this.$().datepicker('setDate', month.toDate());
    this.$().datepicker('show');
  }.observes('controller.controllers.month.content')

});
```

Specifically I'd like to

- handle the `changeDate` event more idiomatically, either in my template or through a `click` handler
- solve the date updating if we start out on a month through data bindings (currently I check if `controllers.month.content` is set, and update the datepicker on `didInsertElement`

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about the bootstrap-datepicker, but i am sure you would have to write a basic integration like this and base your Datepicker upon it. I have done something similar using jQuery UI instead of Bootstrap.

```
// generic logic so that options and event handlers can be declared nicely
App.GenericDatePickerView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var options = this._gatherOptions();

    var datepicker = this.$().datepicker(options);
    this.get("uiEvents").forEach(function(uiEvent){
      datePicker.on(uiEvent, function(){
        var fn = that.get(uiEvent);
        fn.call(that);
      });
    });
    this.set("datepicker", datepicker);
  },
  _gatherOptions: function() {
    var uiOptions = this.get('uiOptions'), options = {};
    uiOptions.forEach(function(key) {
      options[key] = this.get(key);
    }, this);

    return options;
  }
});

App.YourDatePicker = App.GenericDatePickerView.extend({
    uiOptions : ["format", "minViewMode"],
    uiEvents : ["onChange"],

    format : "M yyyy",
    minViewMode : "months",
    onChange : function(){
        var id = this.get("datepicker").data('date').replace(" ", "-");
        this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('month', App.Month.find(id));
    }
});
```

**Note:** I have not tested this code, but this is the basic approach. You declare your options and event handlers on your DatePicker as plain properties. The Generic Class is responsible for passing all those stuff to the underlying datepicker object.

This approach is inspired by a [repo of Luke Melia](https://github.com/lukemelia/jquery-ui-ember/blob/master/js/app.js), which again got inspired by code from Tom Dale & Yehuda Katz, two of the creators of EmberJS.